# How to get updated buffer attributes in Threejs

Tags: three.js

When i apply a matrix to a buffergeometry 
I want to get the updated position attributes fast , i am dealing with 1000000+ vertex .

I have tried Matrix4.applyToBufferAttribute() , but the buffer attribute is still the same

What is the most proper way to perform this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have tried Matrix4.applyToBufferAttribute() , but the buffer attribute is still the same

Then it seems you are doing something wrong in your application. `Matrix4.applyToBufferAttribute()` does apply the matrix to the given attribute. The method is used multiple times in the core of `three.js` for example in `BufferGeometry.applyMatrix()`:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/9f7f38b543c8a51d5614b72c04d657a4cfad68da/src/core/BufferGeometry.js#L141-L142

Ensure to set `BufferAttribute.needsUpdate` to `true` after the method invocation. And yes, it's the intended way to apply a 4x4 transformation matrix to a buffer attribute.

Comment: Does the `BufferAttribute.needsUpdate = true`  change the buffer in the gpu ?

Comment: Correct. When set to `true`, it indicates the engine to update the actual WebGL buffer.

Comment: when i log `meshes[1].applyMatrix(mat);` before it and after it i get the same values
same `Mesh.matrix` , same `Mesh.geometry.attributes.position` , is this normal ?

Comment: `Mesh.matrix` should be identical. The attribute data should actually change. Can you please demonstrate the issue with a [live example](https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/)?